# Subclassing QItemSelectionModel C++/Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I need to subclass `QItemSelectionModel` to handle selection for my specific model.
Mainly for performance reasons, because a method like `QItemSelectionModel::selectedRows()` is really inefficient: it builds selection from scratch every time, sort it and return results from my proxy model.

The best for me would be to override `QItemSelectionModel::emitSelectionChanged(const QItemSelection &newSelection, const QItemSelection &oldSelection)`

But it's a not-virtual method.
Overloading doesn't work either (the View calls the base implementation).

`QItemSelectionModel::select(...)` is the slot that calls `emitSelectionChanged`, but, even if it's virtual, it uses private data with d-pointers and seems pretty bad to override.

Is there any way to bypass this mess?

At the moment i'm using this slot connected to `selectionChanged(...)` signal:

```
void onSelectionChanged(const QItemSelection &selected, const QItemSelection &deselected)
{
    selection.merge(selected, QItemSelectionModel::Select);
    selection.merge(deselected, QItemSelectionModel::Deselect);

    selectedRows.clear();

    if (!selection.isEmpty()) {
        const QModelIndexList &indexes = selection.indexes();
        int columns = proxy->columnCount();

        if (indexes.at(0).row() != indexes.at(1).row()) {
            // Shift selection
            int size = indexes.size() / columns;
            for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
                selectedRows.append(proxy->mapToSource(indexes.at(i)));
            }

        } else {
            // Ctrl selection
            int size = indexes.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i+=columns) {
                selectedRows.append(proxy->mapToSource(indexes.at(i)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the source, if needed: http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/ab4035d522eede6e6fb9251b521ab9e030fa13e3:src/gui/itemviews/qitemselectionmodel.cpp

Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry but overriding it is not the best I think wrapping it may be. but I don't think that you will really improve performance doing this either.