# Selecting many rows in Qt table

Tags: python, performance, qt, pyqt

I am trying to create a `QTableView` in Qt which is efficient for large tables. I've managed to make the display of data efficient by defining my own abstract table model:

```py
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt


class DataTableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):

    def columnCount(self, index=None):
        return 3

    def rowCount(self, index=None):
        return 10000

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if role != Qt.DisplayRole:
            return None
        if orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
            return 'c'
        elif orientation == Qt.Vertical:
            return 'r'

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid():
            return None
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return "({0},{1})".format(index.row(), index.column())

app = QtGui.QApplication([""])
viewer = QtGui.QTableView()
model = DataTableModel()
viewer.setModel(model)
viewer.show()
```

This works fine, because the `data` method is only called for cells that appear in the field of view of the table.

I now want to display an existing selection of some fraction of the rows:

```py
import numpy as np
selected_rows = np.where(np.random.random(10000) > 0.5)[0]
```

I can tell the table widget about this selection by doing e.g.:

```py
smodel = viewer.selectionModel()
for row in selected_rows:
    model_index = model.createIndex(row, 0)
    smodel.select(model_index, QtGui.QItemSelectionModel.Select | QtGui.QItemSelectionModel.Rows)
```

However, this is very inefficient. It typically takes a second to select 1000-2000 rows, when in practice I have tables with millions of rows. There may be ways of speeding up this loop, but I would like to do away with the loop altogether, and instead have Qt only ask me (similarly to the data itself) for information about selections within the visible cells. Is this possible, and if so, what is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You should use the second overloaded version of `select`, the one that accepts a [`QItemSelection`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qitemselection.html) instead of a single index.

The `QItemSelection` is able to select *ranges* of rows by providing the two argument to the constructor:

```
QItemSelection(start_index, stop_index)
```

moreover you can [`merge`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qitemselection.html#merge) the items to become a single selection:

```
selection.merge(other_selection, flags)
```

This suggest to:

1. Sort the indices of the rows you want to select
2. Use `itertools.groupby` to group together consecutive rows
3. Use `createIndex` to get the `QModelIndex` of all start-end indices of these groups
4. Create the `QItemSelection` objects for each group of rows
5. merge all `QItemSelection`s into a single `QItemSelection`
6. Perform the selection over your model.

Note that you want to sort the rows *by index*, not by their values.

Comment: This helps speed things up a little, but doesn't help for a table 10 times larger than the example above because it still requires many calls to ``merge``.

Comment: @astrofrog Well, AFAIK the API doesn't provide anything better than this. Also i found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18581148/subclassing-qitemselectionmodel-c-qt) regarding a C++ program trying to subclass `QItemSelectionModel` and nobody provided an answer that provides an efficient implementation...

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to reimplement the selection model. The view queries the selection model for the selection status of each index. Alas, the `QItemSelectionModel` has a major shortcoming: you can't reimplement its `isSelected` method.

The best you can do is to create a fresh selection model on a model perhaps not attached to any views, then to select the items there, and finally to set the model and selection model on the view.

This is an API shortcoming.

If this is a professional project, you should be compiling your own copy of Qt anyway, under your own git version control, and it's a trivial manner to make the `isSelected` method virtual.

Comment: This was my first instinct, and I made a selection model that re-implemented isSelected, but for some reason that appears to never be called. Any idea why that would be?

Comment: Somewhere in your code you'll have `view.setModel(...); view.setSelectionModel(...);`. If you don't do it in that order it won't work, since `setModel` replaces the selection model, and of course you shouldn't forget to set the selection model either :)

Comment: I'm doing the following: https://gist.github.com/astrofrog/0e78b9f58af2c2d6a07bfed23d502db2 - and I think it should all be in the correct order, but isSelected never gets called unfortunately. Do you have any idea what might be going on?

Comment: @astrofrog. The `isSelected` function isn't *virtual*, so Qt won't call your re-implementation of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display some selected rows only as opposite to 
display everything and select some rows, then QSortFilterProxyModel could help:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt
import numpy as np


class FilterProxy(QtGui.QSortFilterProxyModel):

    afilter = set(np.where(np.random.random(10000) > 0.5)[0])

    def updateFilter(self, new_filter):
        self.afilter = new_filter
        self.invalidateFilter()


    def filterAcceptsRow(self, row, parent):
        if not self.afilter:
            return True
        return row in self.afilter


class DataTableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):

    def columnCount(self, index=None):
        return 3

    def rowCount(self, index=None):
        return 10000

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if role != Qt.DisplayRole:
            return None
        if orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
            return 'c'
        elif orientation == Qt.Vertical:
            return 'r'

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid():
            return None
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return "({0},{1})".format(index.row(), index.column())


class MyWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()

        self.viewer = QtGui.QTableView()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.viewer)

        self.action = QtGui.QAction("Filter x > 0.5", self)
        self.action.triggered.connect(self.updateFilter)
        self.addToolBar("Ffilter").addAction(self.action)

        self.model = DataTableModel()
        self.proxyModel = FilterProxy(self.viewer)
        self.proxyModel.setDynamicSortFilter(True)
        self.proxyModel.setSourceModel(self.model)
        self.viewer.setModel(self.proxyModel)


    def updateFilter(self):
        new_max = np.random.rand(1)[0]
        new_filter = set(np.where(np.random.random(10000) > new_max)[0])
        self.action.setText("Filter x > {}  N = {}".format(new_max, len(new_filter)))
        self.proxyModel.updateFilter(new_filter)



app = QtGui.QApplication([""])
viewer = MyWindow()
viewer.show()
app.exec_()
```